# I am following the symfony fast-track tutorial. and deploy to platform SH is not working?

Tags: php, powershell, symfony, platform

In short I have donwloaded a new book on symfony it uses platform.sh but when I run

```
symfony cloud:project:create --title="Guestbook" --plan=development
```

The porwershell shows an error

```
  exec: "C:\\Users\\ulrik\\.platformsh\\bin\\platform": file does not exist
```

I think I do not have the .platform directory how can I make this command work?

Comment: what is your platform version ?

Comment: I use php 8 It says platform SH? is a tutorial book? But i got stuck in this step?

Comment: I have done this to install the platform cli   PS C:\Users\ulrik\guestbook> scoop bucket add platformsh https://github.com/platformsh/homebrew-tap.git
WARN  The 'platformsh' bucket already exists. To add this bucket again, first remove it by running 'scoop bucket rm platformsh'.
PS C:\Users\ulrik\guestbook> scoop install platform
WARN  'platform' (5.0.1) is already installed.
Use 'scoop update platform' to install a new version.
PS C:\Users\ulrik\guestbook>

Comment: try running symfony project:init  this will create the needed config for platform .platform.app.yaml and .platform/services.yaml and .platform/routes.yaml

Comment: after that try symfony cloud:create --title="Guestbook" --plan=development --set-remote   this will create your project on platform.sh

Comment: then symfony cloud:deploy  to deploy your project and then  symfony cloud:domain:add DEV123.XXX to add your domain

Comment: I have tried but still same situation. Took a print screen.

Comment: Maybe you are running the command from the wrong folder so file gets downloaded to the wrong location.

Comment: Double checked it, the path is inside the guetsbook directory still an error.

Comment: exec: "C:\\Users\\ulrik\\.platformsh\\bin\\platform": file does not exist after the   symfony cloud:create --title="Guestbook" --plan=development --set-remote

Answer (score 1):

This looks as if the CLI installation was not completed successfully. Try re-installing using the instructions on https://symfony.com/download (Windows, I guess?) and then run the command again.

Comment: Updated CLI still same error